# Verilog Multiple Signals Change In Sensitivity List of an Always Block

Tags: verilog

I was wondering whether it was possible for an always block to be executed only when multiple signals in the sensitivity list change together.

As in, suppose I have a signal 'in' and another 'posedge clk'. I want the always block to be executed when BOTH the signals change. Is it possible, and if yes, what is the syntax for it?

Answer (score 3):

In general, no there is no way to do it, as this doesn't actually map to any kind of standard logic cells that one would typically synthesize. However if you describe what your ultimate goal is, I'm sure someone can point you in the right direction while still using synthesizable logic. I'm having a hard time imagining what you could want such a block for.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim! Actually, my purpose of doing this is that I have a module for an accumulator register that has an input port and an input clock too. I want to load data into the accumulator register in the positive edge of the clock cycle only, but then again, this should only be done if the input also changes right?

Comment: Thats why I wanted the always block to execute when both change.

Comment: @Karthik - does the accumulator register just latch the input port, or are you trying to count the number of times the input port changes?

Comment: Hmm, I get what you're saying. Thanks! I have just used 'posedge clk' in the sensitivity list of the always block of my accumulator module, but when I run the code, the accumulator register never changes its value.

Comment: Yes, its meant to latch the input port.

Comment: You can simply just sample the input port on every clock posedge with a d flip flop then. You don't have to manually detect a change on the D pin, because if it doesn't change, then the Q pin stays the same, which is what you were trying to achieve anyway. Flops just sample the input on every clock edge, they don't 'know' if the value has changed or not, and they don't really need to know. @Karthik

Comment: Hmm ok. I guess there's a problem elsewhere in my code then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

**This an answer to the original question, not the problem revealed in the comments**

As @Tim has mentioned there is no hardware construct which can do this. `always @(posedge clk)` create flip-flops which sample the data on the edge of a clk.

`always @*` blocks create combinatorial logic which is evaluated by the simulator when ever the right hand side of an assignment or a select signal changes.

If you had multiple 1 bit signals driven from D-type flip-flops you could XOR (`^`) the input (D) and output (Q) to create a, 1 clock cycle wide, signal indicating the value has changed. These change signals could be combined to create an enable signal. Which is used as a select or enable for a flip-flop.

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    //reset condition
  end
  else if (enabled)
    //Enabled condition
  end
  // no final else, everything will holds its value
end
```

Or may be as the enable for a latch :

```
//synopsys async_set_reset "rst_n"
always @* begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    // Reset 
  end
  else if (latch_open) begin
    //next datavalue
  end
end
```